# React // Change array from child in parent state not working

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components, parent, children

In my parent component "Store" there is a state with an empty array in it (items). The "itemCard" child component is displayed there, also a "Warenkorb (english: cart)" component.

My goal is to add the passed name of the "itemCard" to the empty array after a user finsihed the "slide to order" successfully. Everthing is working, but my this.state.items array is not updating with the passed names. Everthing i tried ended in undefined.

```
//parent component

class Store extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      items: []
    };
    this.handleItems = this.handleItems.bind(this);
  }

  handleItems = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: [...prevState.items, this.props.name]
    })
  )}

  callbackFunction = (childData) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      counter: prevState.counter + 1,
    }));
}

  render() {

    return (
      <Aux>
        <Warenkorb counter={this.state.counter} />
        <StackGrid
          columnWidth="25%"
          gutterWidth={20}
          gutterHeight={20}
          duration={500}
          className="stackGrid"
        >
          <ItemCard key="key1" handleItems={this.handleItems} parentCallback={this.callbackFunction} bgImage={require(`../../assets/jpg/mockupPoster.jpg`)} name="Lorem 1" description="Lorem 1 desc" />
          <ItemCard key="key2" parentCallback={this.callbackFunction} bgImage={require(`../../assets/jpg/mockupPoster.jpg`)} name="Lorem 2" description="Lorem 2 desc" />
          <ItemCard key="key3" parentCallback={this.callbackFunction} bgImage={require(`../../assets/jpg/mockupPoster.jpg`)} name="Lorem 3" description="Lorem 3 desc" />
          <ItemCard key="key4" parentCallback={this.callbackFunction} bgImage={require(`../../assets/jpg/mockupPoster.jpg`)} name="Lorem 4 " description="Lorem 4 desc" />
        </StackGrid>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}


//relevant code from the child component

const { ReactDOM } = window;

class ItemCard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.unlockStartHandler = this.unlockStartHandler.bind(this);
    this.unlockEndHandler = this.unlockEndHandler.bind(this);
    this.animateHandler = this.animateHandler.bind(this);
    this.successHandler = this.successHandler.bind(this);
    this.maxValue = 150;
    this.speed = 12;
    this.currValue = 0;
    this.rafID = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // bind events
    this.inputRange.addEventListener('mousedown', this.unlockStartHandler, false);
    this.inputRange.addEventListener('mousestart', this.unlockStartHandler, false);
    this.inputRange.addEventListener('mouseup', this.unlockEndHandler, false);
    this.inputRange.addEventListener('touchend', this.unlockEndHandler, false);
  }

  // listen for unlock
  unlockStartHandler(e) {
    // clear raf if trying again
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafID);
    // set to desired value
    this.currValue = +e.target.value;
  }

  unlockEndHandler(e) {
      // store current value
      this.currValue = +e.target.value;
      // determine if we have reached success or not
      if(this.currValue >= this.maxValue) {
          this.successHandler();
          this.sendData();
      }
      else {
          this.rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animateHandler);
      }
    }

    // handle range animation
  animateHandler() {
    // update input range
    this.inputRange.value = this.currValue;
    // determine if we need to continue
    if(this.currValue > -1) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animateHandler);
    }
    // decrement value
    this.currValue = this.currValue - this.speed;
  }

  // handle successful unlock
  successHandler = (prevState) => {
    // alert('unlocked');
    // reset input range
    this.inputRange.value = 0;
  };

  sendData = () => {
    this.props.parentCallback(null);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cardWrapper">
        <BackgroundImage bgImage={this.props.bgImage}/>
        <div className="cardBody">
          <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
          <p>{this.props.description}</p>
          <div className="slider">
            <h3>Swipe to order</h3>
            <input
              type="range"
              defaultValue={0}
              min={0}
              max={150}
              className="pullee"
              ref={(el) => { this.inputRange = el; }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: You dont have to bind an arrow function: so remove the binding for handleItems

Comment: can you provide a minimal example? You never call handleItems. And why do you want to add the props name into your array?

Comment: Sry for the delay...Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Van_Gram/szmt503r/11/
What I can't solve in a nutshell: In my Store component there a some ItemCards. In this item card, someone can slide a slider to order a product. If the slide was successful, the Warenkorb component receives an update (+1). Also I want to send the "name" property of the slided ItemCard to the Warenkorb to send it down to the Order component which is displayed in the Warenkorb component. This step is not working and I don't know how to to this. I hope, this makes sense to you? If not, please ask!